# Kubernetes API testing with CURL getting system:anonymous issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

I was trying to run `curl -v -L --cacert cert.crt --key cert.key -k --request GET "https://*my-k8s-server-ip:port*/api/v1/namespaces/testing/services"`, it is showing me the following error:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list resource \"services\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"testing\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 403
}* Connection #0 to host *my-k8s-server-ip* left intact
```

but when I tried with Postman providing the cert and key, it works perfectly fine.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes API Server could not recognize the user in this case which makes it default to `system:anonymous` user.

You need to provide a client certificate using `--cert` parameter which should have the user in CNAME(subject: CN)

`curl -v -L --cacert cert.crt --key cert.key --cert client.crt -k --request GET "https://*my-k8s-server-ip:port*/api/v1/namespaces/testing/services`"

As an alternative you can use the token from a service account as BEARER token as documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#without-kubectl-proxy)